# error: argument of type ‘char (CharStack::)()const throw (CharStack::Underflow)’ does not match ‘char’

Tags: c++, exception, compile-time

The title of the question is the error itself, but I will also include it below:

```
error: argument of type ‘char (CharStack::)()const throw (CharStack::Underflow)’ does not match ‘char’
```

Here is the code file that I am using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CharStack.h"
using namespace std;

// returns top value on stack
// throws exception if empty
//
// O(n)
char CharStack::top() const throw( Underflow )
{
    Elem * cur = head;

    if( !empty() )
    {
        while( cur && cur -> next )
            cur = cur -> next;

        return cur -> info;
    }
}


int main()
{
    CharStack * stack = new CharStack();

    char top = stack -> top;

    stack -> push( 't' );
    stack -> push( 'e' );
    stack -> push( 's' );
    stack -> push( 't' );
    stack -> push( 'i' );
    stack -> push( 'n' );
    stack -> push( 'g' );

    stack -> output( cout );

    delete stack;
}
```

In the header file I define the two exceptions I use, as an example I am following does:

```
     public:
     // exceptions
        class Overflow{};
        class Underflow{};
```

I assume it's because I am not handling the excerption, but I do not how to handle it in this current situation.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return cur -> info;
```

Is `info` a member function that returns a `char`? Then you should be using:

```
return cur -> info();
```

otherwise you're returning a pointer-to-member-function, not a char.

Same for this:

```
char top = stack -> top;
```

`stack->top` is a member function pointer, `stack->top()` is a call to the `top` function of the `stack` object.

BTW, your `top` function doesn't return anything if `empty()` is true, which is illegal. You need to either return a `char`, or throw, but leaving the function without returning or throwing is ill-formed.

Comment: Sorry, an "Elem" is a struct with two variables:

    Elem * next; and char info;

so Elem -> info is just grabbing the char stored in the struct. I should have been more clear.

Comment: The part about `stack->top` being a member function still holds.